# How to support multiple views with the same viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, itemscontrol

What is the best way of using the **same** viewmodel to support multiple views?

(Yes..I have read "MVVM (with WPF)-Binding Multiple Views to the SameViewModel", but if I read it correctly, the answer involved creating different viewmodels which is not what I want to do here).

In the below code the StringViewModel supports the InkStringView when the InkStringView consists of defined rows. I wish now to define a *second* view that consists of columns but must keep the *same* datacontext of StringViewModel. In the second view, the controls have **different** positions and sizes that the StringViewModel *calculates* but thier function and purpose remain the same. It would be ideal if the module that creates the StringViewModels in Strings, an observablecollection, does not know what view will be used leaving the final decision to the xaml of the usercontrol.

My question is how to design either the StringViewModel and/or the DataTemplate to allow for different views and calculations based on that view by changing only the DataTemplate.

(I tried inheriting the StringViewModel to different viewmodels, each viewmodel specific to its view, but it did not work).

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions. Or is their a better way?

Example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StringViewModel}">
               <v:InkStringView_2 />          <----CHANGING THE VIEW TO COLUMNS. ViewModel needs
</DataTemplate>                                    to perform calculations specific to the view.
```

The usercontrol is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StringViewModel}">
               <v:InkStringView />
       </DataTemplate>
   </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
     <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="{Binding Margin}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>      
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Why did the inheriting not work?

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop Strings is ObservableCollection<StringViewModel>.  Using children of StringViewModel did not fit into the Strings collection....I think?? Additionally, this would require the module that built the string collection to know what view is intended, which is not really what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion:

you have a viewmodel MyViewmodel which you wanna display with different DataTemplates. then for me a easy way would be to create "new" Classes with "no" implementation

```
 public class MyT1 : MyViewmodel {}
 public class MyT2 : MyViewmodel {}
 public class MyT3 : MyViewmodel {}
```

so now all MyT1, MyT2, MyT3 have the same methods and stuff, but you can create a datatemplate foreach of them

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyT1}">
           <v:T1View />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyT2}">
           <v:T2View />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyT3}">
           <v:T3View />
   </DataTemplate>
```

or you dont go the Viewmodel First approach and do View First and then you can choose the view you want with your Datacontext

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking, but it still requires the module that builds the String collection to be changed as well as the ItemsSource.  What is View First?

Comment: View First is not so MVVM like :) there you have a view/usercontrol and set the DataContext in codebehind

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, the way I've tackled it is by using `ControlTemplate` so:
In your View:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="Control">
              <Setter Property="Template">
                   <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                              <!-- Here you put you view it could be a UC if you want -->      
                         </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
         </Style
    </Control.Resources>
</Control>
```

Then in your `Style.Resources` you can define `Triggers` or `DataTriggers` to change the `Template` property of your Control. This way you keep the ViewModel as it is and you just change the Views that are getting the data. Hope this makes sense, if anything give us a shout and I'll put more info in.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a simple solution.

Redefine Strings, the ItemsSource, as

```
ObservableCollection<StringViewModelBase> Strings
```

then create children of StringViewModelBase as

```
public class StringByRowViewModel : StringViewModelBase
```

then change the DataTemplate in the resources to be

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StringByRowViewModel}">
        <v:InkStringByRowView />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StringByColumnViewModel}" >
        <v:InkStringByColumnView />
  </DataTemplate>
```

and lastly, I see no choice but to change the module that builds the Strings (at least as far as the viewmodel goes). Instead of

```
 StringViewModelBase svm = new StringViewModelBase(text,color, w);
```

use

```
 StringByColumnViewModel svm = new StringByColumnViewModel(text,color,w);
```

with

```
   Strings.Add(svm);
```

Apparently, the ObservableCollection only needs a common parent and the Data Type is still preservered in the XAML.